# Image Capture fails on colored scan

Tags: macos, mojave, scanning

When I try to scan a document using Image Capture, it shows the following error once it's finished scanning.

[image: Error]

(This time it failed before scanning, but it usually fails after the scanner has recorded the whole paper.)

This happens with both JPEG and PNG formats, and regardless of image resolution.

However, I can do *black and white* scans without issues. The issue occurs only on *colored* scans.

I could scan without any issues on another computer (Windows), with the same scanner and the same cable.

Any ideas?

OS: Mojave v10.14.3

Comment: Do you have a colored printer?

Comment: Could try vuescan.  You can check out the scan quality in the free mode. Free means a water mark.

Comment: @jmh Yes. It's a colored scanner.

Comment: @historystamp Unfortunately it wouldn't suit my needs with a watermark.

Comment: @user3664254  Once you verify that it will scan for you, you pay to get rid of the watermark.  I felt that vuescan produced better quality scans than Image Capture, so I bought it.  https://www.hamrick.com/